# Model.find mongoid 2.x

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

Is possible in `mongoid 2.x` this query?

```
User.find(username: "hyperrjas")
```

I get the error:

```
Mongoid::Errors::DocumentNotFound: Document not found for class User with id(s) {:username=> "hyperrjas"}.
```

In mongoid 3.x is possible with `Model.find_by(username: "hyperrjas")`

As an alternative with `mongoid 2.x` I use

```
Model.find_or_create_by(username: "hyperrjas")
```

**but my question is, if is possible use `Model.find(username: "hyperrjas")` with mongoid 2.x**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the method where instead of find. Find asks for an id.

For more informations : http://two.mongoid.org/docs/querying/criteria.html

(For mongoid 3.x : http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/querying.html)

Comment: Thank you `where` return a criteria. I don't need a criteria. I need finders.

Comment: Then you add .first to get the first result of the rowset. You also can use find_by, but everything is on the documentation.

Comment: Thank you, The best options with mongoid 2.x is `User.first(conditions: {username: "hyperrjas"})`.